# split a large file in multiple files but without case statement

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I'm new in bash scripting and I'm trying to make a script which split a large file in multiple files.
I succeeded with case statement but how can I make it without case statement? For example If I have a file with 30 millions of lines (some database file).
Thank you in advance!

```
echo File which one you want to split
read pathOfFile
echo
countLines=`wc -l < $pathOfFile`
echo The file has $countLines lines
echo
echo In how many files do you want to split?
echo -e "a = 2 files\nb = 3 files\nc = 4 files\nd = 5 files\ne = 10 files\nf = 25 files"
read numberOfFiles
echo
echo The files name with should start:
read nameForFiles
echo

#Split the file
case $numberOfFiles in
a) split -l $(($countLines / 2)) $pathOfFile $nameForFiles;;
b) split -l $(($countLines / 3)) $pathOfFile $nameForFiles;;
c) split -l $(($countLines / 4)) $pathOfFile $nameForFiles;;
d) split -l $(($countLines / 5)) $pathOfFile $nameForFiles;;
e) split -l $(($countLines / 10)) $pathOfFile $nameForFiles;;
f) split -l $(($countLines / 25)) $pathOfFile $nameForFiles;;
*) echo Invalid choice.
esac
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use an array to store values then convert your character to an integer to use as an index:

```
# ...

z=('2' '3' '4' '5' '10' '25')
x=$(( $(printf '%d' "'$numberOfFiles") -97 ))

if  [[ $x -lt "${#z[@]}" ]] && [[ $x -ge '0' ]] ; then
    split -l $(($countLines / ${z[x]})) $pathOfFile $nameForFiles
else
    echo "Invalid choice"
fi
```

As you can see just convert character to ascii then minus 97 will ensure index lines up within the range of array `z`.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to resolve this one, check below:

```
echo File which one you want to split
read pathOfFile
echo
countLines=`wc -l < $pathOfFile`
echo The file has $countLines lines
echo
echo In how many files do you want to split?
read numberOfFiles
echo
echo The files name with should start:
read nameForFiles
echo

#Split the file
if [[ -n ${numberOfFiles//[0-9]/} ]];
        then
        echo You type something else than a number. - Bye
        exit 1
else
        split -l $(($countLines / $numberOfFiles)) -a 3 -d $pathOfFiles $nameForFiles
fi
```